# Prove that the sequence $\left\{\frac{n^2+1}{n+2}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ diverges to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I be able to show that the sequence $\left\{\frac{n^2+1}{n+2}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ diverges to $\infty$?

Here is what I do know: Suppose $M>0$ is given. We must find $N \in \mathrm N$ such that $n \ge N \Rightarrow a_n = \frac{n^2+1}{n+2} > M$. So, we may observe that for any $n \ge 1$...?

And right there is where I get stuck. Can anyone help and explain the next part to me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Finding $N$ will be easy if we observe that $\frac{n^2+1}{n+2}\gt \frac{n^2}{3N}=\frac{N}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

If $n>1$, $$\frac{n^2+1}{n+2}\geqslant \frac{n^2+1}{2n}\geqslant \frac{n^2}{2n}\geqslant \frac n2\to\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{n^2+1}{n+2} = n -2 + \dfrac{5}{n+2}$